# change variable integral over a ball

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

If I have the integral
$$
\int_{\partial B(x_0,r)}f(z)\,d\sigma(z)
$$

over a open ball of center $x_0$ and radius $r$, how can 'move' this integral to the open ball $B(x,\tilde{r})$, where $\tilde{r}>0$, I mean

$$
\int_{\partial B(x_0,r)}f(z)\,d\sigma(z)\to\int_{\partial B(x,\tilde{r})}f(\tilde{z})\,d\sigma(\tilde{z})
$$

My approach was take the change of variable $z\to z-x_0+x$, then
$$
\int_{\partial B(x_0,r)}f(z)\,d\sigma(z)\to\int_{\partial B(x,r)}f(z-x_0+x)\,d\sigma(z)
$$
this change the center of the ball, but I don't know this is correct. Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to do two things: translate from $x_0$ to $x$, and rescale by $\frac {\tilde r}r$. I suggest you consider how to do each separately, without the other, then apply them in succession. Your current answer is obviously not correct, because it doesn't even involve $x_0$.